# Running cob_script_server my_script.py

Tags: ros, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all..

I've been following closely the cob python script tutorial on this [site](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_script_server/Tutorials/Preparing%20a%20new%20script%20%28python%29).

However, I always get this error when i run it:

> rosrun cob_script_server my_script.py

> /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/cob_apps/cob_script_server/scripts/my_script.py:
> line 5: syntax error near unexpected
> token `'cob_script_server'' /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/cob_apps/cob_script_server/scripts/my_script.py: line 5:` roslib.load_manifest('cob_script_server')'

Can someone tell me what is going on and how can i fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9843/running-cob_script_server-my_script.py/) by [weissenrosen](https://answers.ros.org/users/478/weissenrosen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it is a syntax error I suggest you copy-paste the source into your question.

I also notice you seem to be editing files in /opt/ros when you should work somewhere in your home directory. Create a directory somewhere in your home and add `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/the_dir_you_created:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to the end of your ~/.bashrc.
However, this is probably not the source of the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks to me like your script is probably missing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line.  I would also look at Felix's answer for suggestions on where to do these tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1